# How do I get the active theme path in a view?

Tags: views, 8, entities

I need the active theme path in a view to use it in a field rewrite to display that particular image from my theme images folder.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do by

```
global $base_url;
$theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();
$default_image_url = $base_url.'/'. $theme->getPath() .'/images/image.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just reference it.

```
"/themes/mytheme/path/to/images/foo.jpg"
```

Although, IMO this would be a lot simpler by changing the View to show rendered content, and creating a view mode that has all of this in a Twig template instead of fiddle with Views field rewriting.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, You are right but why I am doing this is because I have a content type with a term reference field. For which I am creating a block to show the nodes associated to that term grouped by the term field. But if I use content of teaser then grouping does not work.

Comment: I need the base path as because my drupal installation is in sub directory.

Comment: This is not dynamic and if your theme changes paths it will break.